# How do scientists know they have discovered an element?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, elements

I have a background in math not chemistry and perhaps this question is inappropriate but I will try. I read that after pitchblende was discovered Martin Klaproth in 1879 a latter date discovered that the pitchblende contained another element which he called uranium.

How did he know the uranium was an element and not just another compound that could not be broken down further?  I read Mendeleeve published the periodic table in 1869 but how about before this date? Somehow the first few elements had to be discovered without the benefit of that publication and scientists had to know the substance discoverd and in question was not a compound but an element.

Comment: The question in the title is likely a duplicate of [How were the elements discovered before modern technology?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10855/how-were-the-elements-discovered-before-modern-technology). If your question is specifically about uranium, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium#Discovery) has a brief description of the chemistry allowing to determine that the new element was indeed new. And oh, it's 1789, not 1879. Would be nice if Klaproth lived a bit longer though:)

Comment: Mistakes were not uncommon. Compounds were mistaken for elements and vice versa.

Comment: History tends to remember those who got it right.

Comment: @Karl Except, of course, for [Stigler’s Law of Eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy). ;)

Comment: From @Buttonwood again, here is a bonanza of periodic tables: https://www.meta-synthesis.com/webbook/35_pt/pt_database.php?Button=1950-1999+Formulations. Have fun!

Comment: @Ed V nice link  that will come in handy !!!